# how to align text and image with in anchor tag

Tags: css, image

This is the sample code in which I am trying to position text below the image in a anchor.
I have problems if there are more elements in the html and browser is minimized image and text is going miss aligned

output-'Text' and image and text below the image all should be align'center' and they should stay aligned even if the browser is minimized.

```
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    .cImg {
      width:100%; 
      text-align:center;
    }
    .cImga {
      display:block;
      margin-top:5%;
    }
    .cImgimg {
      position:absolute;
      top:10px;
      bottom:0px;
      right:48%     
    }
  </style>
</head>
<html>
<body>
  <div class="cImg">Text</duiv>
  <div class="cImg">
    <a >
      imageTag/Call us
    </a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `<div class="cImg">Text</duiv>` needs to be fixed.  The closing `div` is misspelled.

Comment: Question asked 1 year ago. You still looking for an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your widths, paddings, and margins need to be in pixels.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your HTML and your CSS.

In your CSS, your style rules are mashed together and are not working properly.  Your HTML has at least one `div` not properly closed.

Also, in your CSS, you should not position the `img` `absolutely`.  This could be contributing to your problems.

I've simplified your HTML and CSS.  This should work.

```
<div class="cImg">
    Text<br />
    <a><img src-"" /><br />
        Call us</a>
</div>

.cImg {
   width:100%; 
   text-align:center;
 }
 .cImg a {
   display:block;
   margin-top:5%;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/B2nXe/